# Netlogo: How to compute sum of items of lists within a list?

Tags: netlogo

I would like to make the sum = the total of pollen recieved by a plant from other plants (Donnors) which is stored in a list of a list (own by each turtle = plant).
The following code make an error (when computing the sum):

> OF expected input to be an agent or agentset but got the list
>   [[119.05593 50 50] [301.25853 50 50] [30.23906 50 50] [460.525845 50
>   50] [55.16717 50 50] [301.25853 50 50]] instead.

Does any one could help me about the mistake in the line "set Tot_pol sum ..." ?
Many thanks for your help.

```
to check-pol [m]                     ;; we check the pollen recieved by the two morphs
set Donnors []                     ;; empty list of pollen donnors
ask zsps with [morph = m]          ;; morph of the pollen reciever
    [
    set totpol 0
    ;; check for pollen donnors and morph for compatiblity within a radius :
    ask zsps with[distance myself <= 20 and morph != m]
        [
        set totpol  (NMaleFlowers * 100 * item round (distance myself) pollination-list)  ;; the farther the less pollen
         set Donnors lput [ (list totpol NMaleFlowers NFemFlowers)] of myself Donnors
      ]

      set Tot_pol sum [ item (position 0 Donnors) Donnors ] of Donnors ;; total of pollen recieved
    ]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Luke's answer is good and should fix your problem. I suspect, however, that you are going to be doing lots of these types of sums. You may wish to set up a `to-report` that you can use for whichever item you want to sum over, just by passing the item number and the name of the list of lists. It would look like this:

```
to-report sum-item [#pos #listoflists ]
  let items map [ x -> item #pos x ] #listoflists
  report reduce [ [a b] -> a + b] items
end
```

The first line extracts the relevant item (remember index from 0) into a new list which the second line sums.

You would then use it with `set Tot_pol sum-item 0 Donnors`

Comment: Dear Luke and Jen, both of your responses greatly helped me in my work. Everything is OK now thanks to you in my code wich runs perfectly. Many thanks for your efforts and time. Dealing with lists is not an easy/obvious task in netlogo for a C++ programmer...(rather cryptic, isnt it ?). Regards, Patrick.

Comment: Agent-based modelling (and hence NetLogo) has a very different way of thinking about the actions and code. I personally hardly ever use lists - they are really only necessary if order is important. Once you get the agent perspective, it will be easier. You may wish to have lots of `print` statements initially to watch as variables change and make sure they are doing what you expect.

Comment: see my additional answer for a more NetLogo way of doing what I think you are trying to do here

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer that is not actually responding to your question. Instead, it is a more NetLogo-ish way of doing what I think you are trying to do with your code.

```
to check-pol [m]
  ask zsps with [morph = m]
  [ let senders zsps with [distance myself <= 20 and morph != m]
    set totpol sum [NMaleFlowers * 100 * round (distance myself)] of senders
  ]
end
```

Your code gets into levels of `ask` that I think are unnecessary. What I think you are doing with your list is keeping track of the pollen donors. But an agentset is a cleaner approach and then you can simply pull out the information you want from the agentset using `of`.

Further, when you `ask zsps with[distance myself <= 20 and morph != m]` to `set` variable values in your code, then THOSE agents (not the receiving agent) are the ones having their variables changed. I think you are trying to take the perspective of the receiver of pollen, who looks around and received pollen from the other agents that are close enough. So the receiving agent should have the value changed.

This is not tested.

Comment: Yes, you are rigth. My goal is  to keep track of pollen donnors from the point of vew of the receiver. Thank you for this remark about the code. This was a bad mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after here (you may want to look at the [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but if I'm reading you right you want the sum of the first item for each entry in the `Donners` list.

As to why your approach didn't work- NetLogo is telling you with that error that you've used `of` with a list, but `of` only works with agents or agentsets. Instead, you have to use a list processing approach. The simplest way might be to use `sum` in conjunction with `map first` in order to get what you need:

```
to sum-first-item
  let example-list [ [ 1 2 3 ] [ 4 5 6 ] [ 7 8 9 ] ]
  let sum-of-firsts sum map first example-list
  print sum-of-firsts
end
```

To translate to `Donnors`, try:

```
set Tot_pol sum map first Donnors
```

That should work, but without reproducible a code example I can't check.