# Netlogo: Sum a list of lists of equal length element-wise

Tags: netlogo

I have a list of lists of equal lengths, e.g.

```
[[0 1 0] [2 3 0] [4 4 2] [0 1 0]]
```

How can I get the list `[6 9 2]` which sums up the entries in the four lists entrywise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let _lst [[0 1 0] [2 3 0] [4 4 2] [0 1 0]] show reduce [[?1 ?2] -> (map + ?1 ?2)] _lst
```

As a procedure:

```
to-report aggregate-lists [list-of-lists]
  report reduce [[?1 ?2] -> (map + ?1 ?2)] list-of-lists
end
```

Comment: This solves the problem I stated perfectly. It does not solve related problems for other aggregation functions like entry-wise `median` (instead of `sum`) which cannot be processed by successively as `reduce` does it.

Comment: @janlo I suppose you should only expect an answer to a question you actually asked.  But feel free to ask your new question separately.

Answer (score 1):

Someone who is better at lists will come along and do this more cleanly, but this works.

```
to testme
  let inlist [[0 1 0] [2 3 0] [4 4 2] [0 1 0]]
  let outlist []
  let ii 0
  while [ii < length item 1 inlist ]
  [ let items map [ x -> item ii x ] inlist
    print items
    set outlist lput reduce [ [a b] -> a + b] items outlist
    set ii ii + 1
  ]
  print outlist
end
```

What it does it create a list of the first entries (with `let items`) and then sums them with the `reduce`, then moves to the second entries etc.

You may also want to look at this question [Netlogo: How to compute sum of items of lists within a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949637/netlogo-how-to-compute-sum-of-items-of-lists-within-a-list), which works with individual entries.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a "one-liner" and finally produced it:

```
to-report aggregate-lists [list-of-lists]
   report map [ i -> sum (map [li -> item i li] list-of-lists) ] range length item 0 list-of-lists
end
```

You map a reporter which sums `item i` of all lists to the vector of indices `range length item 0 list-of-lists` (would be `[0 1 2]` in the example).

Comment: This also applies for other entry-wise aggregations like `median` instead of sum.